# How to draw bordered text?

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to draw bordered Text on Graphics, as shown below.  The text color is black, and the border is white.

How to draw something like this example?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this will most likely not look as good as your sample picture, you can try to draw your text with white color for several times using slightly shifted starting coordinates (by 1 or 2 pixels). Then set graphics color to black and draw your text using your true starting coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write bordered text directly, by modifying the font style of a `TextField` for example. Though as Jonathan suggested you can display the raw image using `BitmapField`. Have a look at this:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Bitmap_field_1303007_11.jsp